# Game Center Real-time match - How many players?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, game-center

I want to program a new game for the iPhone. How many people can I put in one match via the Game Center Real-Time match API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 to 4 players.
Up to 16 players for turnbased matches.

Answer (score 0):

I turn based match we can add player's 2 to 16.

The study my experience good tutorial is, Raywenderlich's there are two parts, Check it :)

[Ray Wenderlich's Turn based part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1)

[Ray Wenderlich's Turn based part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5509/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-2)